# static files problem, everything is loaded except some files style.css and js

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-3.0

my template didn't work and can't get static files but I did everything.
I just can't get style.css but other files are loaded. only style and some js files isn't loaded but the path is not wrong . please help me

[this is an image of my folder and project tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2G8x1.png)

Settings for Static and media.

```
STATIC_URL = '/temfiles/'
MEDIA_URL = '/mediafiles/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/uploads/')
X_FRAME_OPTIONS = 'SAMEORIGIN'
```

my project URL file

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('blog.urls')),
    path('froala_editor/', include('froala_editor.urls'))

]
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,
                      document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

my app URL file

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name = 'index'),
    path('<slug:slug>/', views.post_detail, name='Post Detail')
]+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

my Views File

```
def index(request):
    Post_list = BlogPost.objects.all()
    template_name = 'front/index.html'
    return render(request, template_name,{"Post_list":Post_list})



def post_detail(request):
    return render(request, 'front/post_detail.html')
```

my base template CSS example

```
   {% load static %}
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 
  'front/css/style.css' %}">
```

[Static Directory Tree image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/58mG5.png)

[static directory tree with open folders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JK5d6.png)

[browser inspect terminal picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6cZHB.png)

[style CSS URL in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jnAsz.png)

[MY urls.py for static and media root](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GhZZR.png)

Comment: do you have `django.contrib.staticfiles` in your `INSTALLED_APPS`? also are you running in `DEBUG=True` mode?

Comment: yes ruddra  everything is loading exept style.css and some files

Comment: DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'froala_editor',
    'blog.apps.BlogConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

Comment: do you have your code on `github` so , I can try, I faced this issue once but can't remember how I solved it.